# how to hide div if current index belong to specific array (angular Js)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="x in vm.arr" ng-if="$index!=x">
 Hello
<div>
```

i want to hide Div if index belong to any of arr 
example : if arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
if index = 1 
div must disappear

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more. The condition to hide is not very clear. You want to hide when exactly ?

Comment: `x.indexOf($index) === -1`, But I'd suggest create a function that takes index and return boolean value

Comment: it's exactly what i want thank you

Comment: @amalmansour Please check all answers. I have added a sample with function. If you need any clarification, just tag

Comment: @amalmansour please look in the example from here http://codepen.io/santoshshinde2012/pen/oBXrQL and check the following answer why to use ng-if not ng-hide.

Comment: @Rajesh Thank you very much , you solve My Problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> ng-view="value"

where when value is equal to true the element will be viewed while when it will be false it angular will add a display type of hidden to the element to hide it

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="x in vm.arr" ng-if="vm.arr.indexOf($index) == -1">
 Hello
</div>
```

Comment: It should be `=== -1`

Answer (score 0):

This case will be handle with `ng-if` & `ng-hide` angular directives.

For Example :

```
 <div ng-repeat="x in vm.arr track by $index">
    <div ng-if="showDiv($index)" >  
      Hello {{$index}}
    </div>
 <div>
```

In controller write the function

```
   $scope.x = [1,2,3,4];
   $scope.showDiv = function(index) {
           return index === 1 ? false : true;
   }
```

Both `ng-show` and `ng-if` receive a condition and hide from view the directive’s element in case the condition evaluates to false. The mechanics they use to hide the view, though, are different.

`ng-show` (and its sibling `ng-hide`) toggle the appearance of the element by adding the CSS display: none style.

`ng-if`, on the other hand, actually removes the element from the DOM when the condition is false and only adds the element back once the condition turns true.

For example check codepen from [here](http://codepen.io/santoshshinde2012/pen/oBXrQL) & more explanation from [here](http://www.codelord.net/2015/07/28/angular-performance-ng-show-vs-ng-if/).

Hopes this will help you !!

Answer (score 0):

for that you can use `ng-hide` directive of angularjs. It can be used to show or hide some elements.

If the value of the `ng-hide` is true then that element is hidden else it is visible.

You can take reference from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide

Answer (score 0):

As commented,

> you should consider creating a wrapper function that takes `index` as argument and returns visibility.

Benefit of this approach would be that you'll have more control over conditions and cases.

#### Sample

```js
function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.selectedIndex = [];
  $scope.data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
  $scope.length = 5;

  $scope.toggleDiv = function(index) {
    var i = $scope.selectedIndex.indexOf(index);
    i >= 0 ? $scope.selectedIndex.splice(i, 1) : $scope.selectedIndex.push(index)
  }

  $scope.showDiv = function(index) {
    return x.indexOf(index) === -1
  }
}
```

```css
.button {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.selected {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in data" ng-if="showDiv($index)">
      {{item}}
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in data">
      <span class="button" ng-class="{selected:!showDiv($index)}" ng-click="toggleDiv($index)">{{item}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```